# How to call a non-static method from static method in JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a non-static method from static method. Both are in same class.
How can I achieve this ?

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("in constructor props =", this.props.mainData);
    this.state = {
        data: null,
        isFetch: false,
        clickEvent: false
    }
    this.allDataShow = this.allDataShow.bind(this);
    this.upcomingShow =  this.upcomingShow.bind(this);
}

allDataShow(){
    allData(this.props.mainData);
}

upcomingShow(){
    upcoming(this.props.mainData);
}


static changeData(option) {
    console.log("I'm home changeData");
    switch (option) {
        case "All":
            console.log("All");
            allDataShow();
            break;

        case "Upcoming":
            console.log("Upcoming");
            console.log("this",this);
            inst.prototype.upcomingShow();
            break;
   }
}
render(){...}
}
```

This is updated code in which I am calling changeData in another component, and in changeData I call non-static method. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-static method will be on the prototype, so reference `My.prototype` or `this.prototype` (`this` will refer to `My` inside the static method):

```js
class My{
    static my1(){
        this.prototype.my2();
    }
    my2(){
        console.log("my2 is executing");
    }
}

My.my1();
```

That said, this is very weird - non-static methods are generally useful to refer to and use *instance* data. If the method uses instance data, it will need an instance to run sensibly. If the method doesn't use instance data, it probably shouldn't be a prototype method, but a static method or a standalone function.

Comment: I used your solution. But it gives error 
 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'my2' of undefined". Actually my question is related to React.js.

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" to see the code working - it logs `my2 is executing` as desired. If it doesn't work in the code on your machine, please post the code on your machine, since it's different from what you have in the question.

Comment: my code is related to React.js. I updated my code please take a look.

Comment: Your question still shows the same code, with no React involved. The code in my answer solves your problem for the code you've posted

Answer (score 2):

You must instantiate a new "My" class and then call from there. You can either require the class as a parameter or make a new one in the method.

```
class My{
    static my1(instance){
        //something like this
        instance.my2();
    }
    my2(){
        console.log("my2 is executing");
    }
}

var myInstance = new My();
My.my1(myInstance);
```

OR

```
class MyOther{
    static my1(){
        //something like this
        var myInstance = new My();
        myInstance.my2();
    }
    my2(){
        console.log("my2 is executing");
    }
}

MyOther.my1();
```